# Painters algorithm test 2

Tags: view, graphics, polygon, viewport, surface

TEST #2:
Surface S is completely behind the
overlapping  surface relative to the viewing
position.

S1 is completely behind/inside the overlapping surface S2 [image]

How to check these conditions?

i) Set the plane equation of S2(Ax + By + Cz + D = 0), such that the surface S2 is towards the viewing position.

ii) Substitute the coordinates of all vertices of Substitute the coordinates of all vertices of S1(x', y',z') into the plane equation of S2 and check for the sign.

iii) If all vertices of S1 are inside S2  then S1 is behind S2. (Fig. 1).

i. e. Ax' + By' + Cz' + D < 0 ,x', y', z' are S1 vertices.

iv) If all vertices of S1 are outside  S2  then S1 in front of S2.

My first question is why all vertices of one polygon(S1) substitute in the plane of another(S2) and value is less than 0 then we say S1 is behind S2? I don't understand when value less than 0 by the vertices of one polygon then we say one is behind another?

My second question  is when Test #2 is passed (i.e. S1 is completely behind/inside the overlapping surface S2) why we coloring S1 first before S2. There is no necessitates to S1 because S1 is totally obscured
by S2. So why we colored S2?

Comment: I guess that you are making a confusion between behind and inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you consider the implicit equation of a plane, f(x, y, z) = ax + by + cz + d = 0, it should be clear that the points that make f(x, y, z) positive [or negative] are on the same side of the plane. Hence the sign test.
- If S1 is not completely hidden by S2, painting S1 first will work. So you needn't test the "completely" condition.

Comment: @Daoust But I don't understand why one polygon vertices are satisfied of plane of another polygon, then we decide which one is behind another?

Comment: @Daoust "all vertices of one polygon(S1) substitute in the plane of another(S2) and value is less than 0 then we say S1 is behind S2"--why?

Comment: @Daoust I have drawn.. then?

Comment: @Daoust okay ....then?

Comment: @Sood: apply the sign test.

Comment: @Daoust Okay.. My confusion is here. Two polygons are parallel which hides another I. e behind the another, but why we check one points of one on another?

Comment: @Daoust by sign checking of one polygon surface Ax + By + Cz + D = 0..

Comment: @Daoust, please help me to understand.. I am really struggling to understand.. I am imploring you.

Comment: @Sood: that's precisely what I am trying to do. Didn't you notice ?

Comment: @Sood: I asked two questions. I don't know to which you answered.

Comment: @Daoust if I have one polygon surface Ax + By + Cz + D = 0 . Then any point (x', y', z')  inside the polygon if Ax' + By' + Cz' + D < 0 otherwise outside

Comment: @Sood: no, behind.

Comment: @Daoust (x', y', z') is not the vertices of another polygon. It the vertices of same polygon Ax + By + Cz + D = 0.Then any point (x', y', z') inside the polygon if Ax' + By' + Cz' + D < 0 otherwise outside. AmbI correct?

Comment: how? Polygon surface equation Ax + By + Cz + D = 0 is same with plane equation?

Comment: @AlokMaity: stop confusing behind and inside. I am leaving this dialogue of the deaf. You should delete your comments.

Comment: could any link by which I can understand points inside polygon by the equation?